# Purging sensitive data from shared computer. Chrome hangs during this process

Tags: google-chrome, purge

I have used a shared computer for a while, logging to Chrome with my personal account. When I was done I wanted to purge my sensitive data using standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> dialog. However, it turned out that Chrome hangs each time I open this dialog (tried about twenty times).

How can I purge my sensitive data in this situation?

Uninstalling Chrome is not an option due to missing privileges / unknown admin password. Formatting hard drive is also not an option in my case, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never login to Chrome on shared computer. Login to particular service (like Gmail) instead.

Second of all, if your Chrome hangs on clearing private data screen then you can:

1. Click on user button (leftmost button in top-right corner) and go to user management.
2. Hover selected user with a mouse, click on three-dot button that will appear in top-right corner.
3. Remove this user by selecting last item in context menu.
4. Confirm your decision.

This will remove all sensitive data that belongs to that particular user / profile.

Note that Chrome hangs not on "purge personal data" view, but actually on opening settings. This was observed by me in many situations and Chrome version, on many devices. You can confirm this by trying to see Chrome version or changing your managing installed lanugages. In all these versions Chrome will hang.